# Change form based on the login username

Tags: php, session

On my home page I have a login form. Can it be changed to something else based on the the username that has been logged in?

For example

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="testconnect.php">
  <p>
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="text" name="password" id="password" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Submit" />
  </p>
</form>
```

Can this be changed on the homepage to show

> Welcome Back "Username". Logout

Comment: Could you try for it later ? Just before asking any question, search for it.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_intro.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I understand correctly you want to hide the form if the user is already logged in and display their username in a message instead? Yes, you can do that. If you are using PHP sessions to store the user data, you could do something like this:

```
<?php
// Make sure to start a session first
if(!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}

// If a username is set, display a welcome message.
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    echo "Welcome back " . $_SESSION['username'];
} else {
    // No login session found, output the form here instead
?>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="testconnect.php">
  <p>
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="text" name="password" id="password" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Submit" />
  </p>
</form>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put login data in `$_COOKIE` and if you find cookie echo 'Hello username' else echo your form

Comment: I would prefer session instead of cookie.

Comment: Well the principle is the same, whatever shuffle 1990 prefers :)

Comment: I would prefer: session + webstorage